Why does an array of even numbers contain empty values?
Why does an array of even numbers contain empty values?


function getEvenNumbers(arr) {
  const evenNumbers = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 === 0) {
      evenNumbers[i] = arr[i]
    }
  }
  return evenNumbers;
}
console.log(getEvenNumbers([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]));



console output: [empty, 2, empty, 4, empty, 6]

Because as you walk through each element in the array and check it, you only add the even number to the new array, and skip it when it's odd, leaving the new array entry for the odd spots as undefined

The value should be assigned when the if condition is passed. Why is the value assigned when the condition check fails?

Because you step through the original array one element at a time, and when you build your second array, you're placing the even numbers in the same index positions as the original array (indices 1, 3, and 5). That's leaving indices 0, 2, and 4 undefined. Instead of doing what you're doing, just push the matches onto the new array. I think someone had left a comment earlier about doing that with .push() but it's gone now.

Thank you so much! Now I understand how the array is formed by the loop. Thank you again.

it's because you're assigning at index i
function getEvenNumbers(arr) {
    const evenNumbers = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 === 0) {
            evenNumbers[i] = arr[i]
        }
    }
    return evenNumbers;
}
console.log(getEvenNumbers([1,2,3,4,5,6]));

or given this array
evenNumbers[1] = 2
evenNumbers[3] = 4
evenNumbers[5] = 6

with javascript filling up the empty space. you should use evenNumbers.push(arr[i]) instead

It is because you are assigning a value to the i-th index of the array.
Since the odd value is skipped, they appear to be empty.
You can push even numbers to the evenNumbers array.
function getEvenNumbers(arr) {
    const evenNumbers = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 === 0) {
            evenNumbers.push(arr[i])
        }
    }
    return evenNumbers;
}
console.log(getEvenNumbers([1,2,3,4,5,6]));

Even more, you can use Array.filter() function to do the same work.
function getEvenNumbers(arr) {
    return arr.filter(n=>n%2===0);
}
console.log(getEvenNumbers([1,2,3,4,5,6]));

